# Getting a null pointer for GCM registration id when called from main activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am making an app wherein the students will get push notification on their devices.
    For this i need to login first,when login is succesful i call the register method of gcm...but when i do this i get a null pointer on my register method...
    but when i call the register method on Oncreate of main activity it gives me the registration id.

Please someone suggest me how am i suppose to call the register method from main activity 
    Below is my code.

Async class for registration::

```
    void registerInBackground() {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String msg = "";
                    try {
                        if (gcm == null) {
                            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                        }
                        regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                        System.out
                                .println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++THIS IS MY REG ID FROM ASYNC+++++++++++++++++++++++++"
                                        + regid);
                        msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                        if (regid == null) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&REGISTRATION ID IS NULL&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
                        }

                        sendRegistrationIdToBackend(regid);

                        storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                        // if (msg == "SERVICE_NOT_FOUND") {
                        //
                        // }

                        // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                        // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                        // exponential back-off.
                    }
                    // will give on screen
                    return msg;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                    System.out
                            .println("**********THIS IS POST FROM ASYNC***************************"
                                    + msg);
                    mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");

                    // if (msg == null) {
                    // registerInBackground();
                    // }
                    // mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
        }
```

**The main Class from where i am call this method::**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    MainActivityPushNotification mainHttp = new MainActivityPushNotification();
    mainHttp.registerInBackground();
}
```

The moment i run this code i get a null pointer on `regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);`
    and when i run the registartion class as my startup class then i am getting my registration id.
    Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This Is because of Gcm server get some time to Create registration id you have to call this for some times i mean you have to create method which get regId and call it 5 times 1 sec interval and when get RegId break loop.

Comment: can u please tell me,like should i call this method from the main activity??

Comment: ok...so u mean in postExcecute i add a loop which when returns a value will go to the main activity? rite? But my requirement is when the login is successful i shld register in an async task and simultaneously show the dashboard UI

Comment: then register to server in doInbackgroud and when you are successfully register then use runonuithread in doinbackground method and display your UI.